# How to detect that where is new child added in specified node?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Currently i build up chat app in which i want to create notification by self instead of FCM.
This is my json data

```
{
  "Message": {
    "SenderUID": {
      "CurrentUID": {
        "message_push_id": {
          "name": "abcd",
          "from": "abcd",
          "time": "abcd",
          "status": "abcd"
        },
        "message_push_id1": {
          "name": "abcd",
          "from": "abcd",
          "time": "abcd",
          "status": "abcd"
        },
        "message_push_id2": {
          "name": "abcd",
          "from": "abcd",
          "time": "abcd",
          "status": "abcd"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "SenderUID2": {},
  "CurrentUID": {
    "message_push_id3": {
      "name": "abcd",
      "from": "abcd",
      "time": "abcd",
      "status": "abcd"
    },
    "message_push_id4": {
      "name": "abcd",
      "from": "abcd",
      "time": "abcd",
      "status": "abcd"
    },
    "message_push_id5": {
      "name": "abcd",
      "from": "abcd",
      "time": "abcd",
      "status": "abcd"
    }
  }
}
```

In this json stusture "message_push_id" generated every time when new message appear.**So i want to get detail of new message(child) from Message node**

For this i used below codes

```
     Messageref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot uid: dataSnapshot.getchildren()) {
             String senderUIDKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
             if (!senderUIDKey.equal(currentuid)) {
              Messageref.child(senderUIDKey).child(currentuid).addChildEventListener(childEventListener) = new ChildEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                String pushkey= dataSnapshot.getKey());

                Messsage messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messsage.class);
                //Here i also used single value event listener of location //
Messageref.child(currentuid).child(senderUIDKey).child(pushkey)//for Main operation//
               }
              }
             }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
             System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
           });
```

**Instead of this code Is it possible to get message detail directly?**
Here i trying to get new added child detail.,for this,
1. I used addValueEventListener to retrieve senderUIDKey In Messageref.
2. And after getting  senderUID from ValueEventListener i used ChildEventListener to retrieve new child and its key.

Comment: What do you mean through "directly"?

Comment: Suppose new child(new message) will appear ,than get this child detail only by any one listener...
Here i used ValueEventlistener and than inside of it used childeventlistner.,,,
By this ValueEventListener read everytime all nodes when new childAdded(onDatachange), To avoid read all data get directly new child detail.

Comment: In short get location of new added child in the Message node, and by the use of this location i will get message detail

Comment: No, you cannot get more "directly" unless you change you structure.

Comment: in other word Detect where to  added new child in Messageref ?

Comment: I'm afraind I didn't understand you.

Comment: Please see my corrected question